# Error on converting Jquery val().split() to Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the process of converting my code from Jquery to Vanilla JS I have this code snippet that I can't convert:

```
function updateTextBox(nehemyah) {
  var delfino = $("#campotxt").val().split("\n");
  delfino.remove(nehemyah);
  $("#campotxt").val(delfino.join("\n"));
}
```

I tried this:

```
let camPito = document.getElementById("campotxt");
function updateTextBox(nehemyah) {
    let delfino = camPito.value;
    delfino = delfino.split("\n");
    delfino = delfino.remove(nehemyah);
    delfino = delfino.join("\n");
  }
```

The idea is that this `textarea` is cleared line per line once I press a button. If I use that Jquery snippet it works without problem.

Comment: probaby erroring on this line `delfino.remove(nehemyah);`. what is that meant to do? `remove()` is called on a DOM element and you're calling it on an array

Comment: just the textarea with the id in the snippet :(

Comment: There is no array remove.... unsure how the jQuery version works.

Comment: You never set the value back into the textarea. You set the .val() in the jQuery version, but do not set the .value in the JavaScript one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.remove()` is not a standard method, so I guess you've defined that elsewhere in your code. It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Since this line isn't jQuery, there's no reason to change it. Presumably it doesn't return the array, it just modifies it in place, so you shouldn't assign the result back to the variable.

You're not assigning the final result back to the value of the input.

```js
function updateTextBox(nehemyah) {
  let camPito = document.getElementById("campotxt");

  let delfino = camPito.value.split("\n");
  delfino.remove(nehemyah);
  camPito.value = delfino.join("\n");
}
```

Comment: Working, thank you so muuuuch bro

Comment: I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73664430/19856237) on StackOverflow about a problem converting AJAX from Jquery to Vanilla JS, do you think you could help me? I would really appreciate it :(